# papervision 3d ridiculously slow on air for iOS

Tags: ios, performance, flash, air, papervision3d

My game uses air for ios 3.5 gpu mode and when making a 24x24 segments Sphere using papervision, the game's FPS drops significantly on mobile devices like iPad. I Can't even display a single rough sphere if I were to maintain the game's FPS at high.

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong or is papervision not suitable for Air for iOS? Also is there any fast rendering 3d library that can run with gpu rendering mode? At this point the development has gone too far to switch it back to direct rendering mode

Comment: You'll need to use a library that is based on Stage3D (eg Away3D) - which Papervision isnt AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Papervision is not an active 3d lib, for 60fps rendering you have to use a 3D hardware accelerated flash framework like one of those :

Away3d
demo : http://away3d.com/showcase/

Flare3d
demo : http://www.flare3d.com/showcase/

edit
<strike>Minko
demo : aerys.in/portfolio/mercedes-e500</strike>

<strike>Alternativa3D
demo : alternativaplatform.github.com/Alternativa3D/Demos/ParticlesDemo/</strike>

And yes they all works on an ipad :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll check them out